# UglifyJS2 throwing TypeError on .array("reserved-file")

Tags: javascript, minify

I wrote a simple bash script to automatically minify some repositories for me using mishoo/UglifyJS2 with this line of code:

```
../bower_components/UglifyJS2/bin/uglifyjs src/* -c -m -o ${minifiedFile}
```

It works great on my Mac but my coworker is unable to run it with the following error:

```
C:\Users\User\uabshp\bower_components\UglifyJS2\bin\uglifyjs:111
   .array("reserved-file")
    ^

TypeError: yargs.usage(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).describe(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).alias(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).string(...).array is not a function
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\uabshp\bower_components\UglifyJS2\bin\uglifyjs:111:6)
   at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
   at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
   at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
   at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

Is this a Windows compatibility issue or is there something missing with the setup? I have already had to switch from compressJs to try getting minify to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution but it works for me. I removed the lines causing me trouble in `UglifyJS2/bin/uglifyjs.js`.

Line number 72:

```
.describe("reserved-file", "File containing reserved names")
```

Line number 77:

```
.describe("pure-funcs", "List of functions that can be safely removed if their return value is not used")
```

.
Line numbers 111-112:

```
.array("reserved-file")
.array("pure-funcs")
```

Line numbers 536-554:

```
ast.walk(new UglifyJS.TreeWalker(function(node){
        if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Seq) return; // descend
        if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Assign) {
            var name = node.left.print_to_string({ beautify: false }).replace(/-/g, "_");
            var value = node.right;
            if (constants)
                value = new Function("return (" + value.print_to_string() + ")")();
            ret[name] = value;
            return true;    // no descend
        }
        if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Symbol || node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Binary) {
            var name = node.print_to_string({ beautify: false }).replace(/-/g, "_");
            ret[name] = true;
            return true;    // no descend
        }
        print_error(node.TYPE)
        print_error("Error parsing arguments for flag `" + flag + "': " + x);
        process.exit(1);
    }));
```

The removed lines will obviously effect functionality but it still works for my purposes. If anyone has a better solution I will mark it.